# Effective Java: Make constructors private or package-private

Tags: java, inheritance, factory, final

From Chapter 4 of [Effective Java](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA77&ots=yZHnKgs0P1&dq=way%20to%20do%20it.%20The%20alternative%20to%20making%20an%20immutable%20class%20final%20is%20to%20make%20all%20of%20its%20constructors%20private%20or%20package-private%2C%20and%20to%20add%20public%20static%20factories%20in&pg=PA78#v=onepage&q&f=false) the following example is given:

```
public class Complex { 
    private final double re; 
    private final double im;

    private Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    public static Complex valueOf(double re, double im) {
        return new Complex(re, im);
    }
    ... // Remainder unchanged
}
```

> [...] It is the most flexible because it allows the use of multiple package-private implementation classes. To its clients that reside outside its package, the **immutable class** is effectively final because **it is impossible to extend a class that comes from another package** and that lacks a public or protected constructor.

I understand that the class is effectively `final`,

**but is there any actual advantage from not declaring it `final`?**

Omitting this keyword when the class doesn't support extension seems like a less clear way to communicate how the `API` is meant to be used. Or was `final` only left out here to show the reader that non-extendable, non-final classes are possible?

Comment: `it allows the use of multiple package-private implementation classes` which is not a behaviour you'd get with final

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main benefit is to limit the scope of inheritance. Declaring it `final` will make it sealed everywhere; however, sometimes as an author of the class you would like to inherit the `class` within the same package or class file but you don't want others to do the same. And that's what this trick will do.

It's a nightmare to change a class that is open for inheritance (Commonly used APIs). If you can limit the scope of inheritance, then it becomes a simple refactoring job.

Comment: But the constructor is still private. That would mean only nested classes can actually extend this class. So wouldn't it still be considered final for other top level classes in the same package?

Comment: @flkes I'm with you on this. The sentence beginning `To its clients that reside outside its package` is slightly misleading, as this also applies to clients inside the same package but in a different top-level class. I think this example would make more sense if the constructor had been package-private, or if the text had made clear that only nested classes could actually extend it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the advantage:
"... it allows the use of multiple package-private implementation classes"

If it were final, extension would be impossible (either inside or outside the package). In this way you can create another class inside the package that extends Complex (provided the constructor is package private, that is).